# How to cut a number (positive or negative or float) from a string (SQL server)?

Tags: sql-server

I have some dirty data like:

```
100 mb
-10 мегабит!
-
1.20 
100
hello -10 mb
```

Or something like that.
I saw a lot of solutions how to retrieve an integer from a string with SQL Server. But I have not found anything about float or negative value.

Could anybody, please, share some solution to do this? I need something to have:

```
100
-10
1.20
100
-10
```

Comment: I would suggest fixing your design, if I am honest.

Comment: My best suggestion would be splitting the string on a delimiter (a space (`' '`) seems appropriate here), and the trying to convert said string. Of course, if you have grammar in your value, that could be a problem though. For example `'That''s 10.12.'` would not successfully convert `'10.12.'` to a numerical value (as it appears to have 2 decimal places).

Comment: A client-side regex could do this quite effectively. In T-SQL you have no access to any advanced string processing, so it's nothing but pain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible easy way of handling this would be a UDF that you can pass the string through.

This would not be advisable if you have many (1000s) of rows (due to inlining and rbar processing) but for single values or a few hundred rows it would be absolutely fine.

A function something like the following:

```
create or alter function dbo.NumbersOnly(@String varchar(100))  
returns varchar(100)
as  
begin
    declare @len smallint=0, @i smallint=0, @result varchar(100)=''
    select @len=Len(@String)

    while @i <=@len
    begin
        if Ascii(Substring(@String,@i,1)) in(45,46,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57)
            set @result=@result + Substring(@String,@i,1) 
        set @i=@i+1
    end

    return @result

end
go
```

And then

```
select dbo.NumbersOnly('Hello 15.95 mum')

= 15.95
```

Comment: Thank you! Looks good, but what about the negative values?

Comment: @Aleksej_Shherbak I've edited above to include `-` in the list of allowed characters. It depends on your particular use-case if this is good enough or needs further parsing. For example if there were additional `-` characters elsewhere in the string they might need removing with additional logic. Recommend using the returned value in a `try_cast`